# Avoid multiple network calls with hooks and Apollo

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, apollo, react-apollo

I have a hook that makes an Graphql call

```
export const useGetStuff = (options?: QueryHookOptions<GetStuffResponse, GetStuffQueryArgs>) => {
    const [stuffId] = useStuffId();

    return useQuery<GetStuffResponse, GetStuffQueryArgs>(getStuff, {
        variables: { stuffId },
        notifyOnNetworkStatusChange: true,
        skip: !stuffId,
        ssr: false,
        ...options,
    });
};
```

And I am using this hook in one another hook

```
const useCustomHook = () => {
    // some unrelated stuff
    const { data: stuffData, loading } = useGetStuff();
   
    // do logic with stuffData and other unrelated stuff

    return { someProperty };
    
}
```

and in some component, I am using both `useGetStuff` and `useCustomHook`.

```
const MyComponent = () => {
    const { someProperty } = useCustomHook();
    const { data ,loading } = useGetStuff();

    // stuff
    
}
```

This implementation causes the `getStuff` query to be called twice (two network calls).

Is there a simple way to avoid that without having to keep `useGetStuff` only in the custom hook, since this latter should not have to be returning the `stuffData`.

Comment: You're calling useGetStuff twice, so it runs twice..

Comment: Yes I'm looking for way to avoid that, or even better if I can call that hook twice but have the network call only once.

Comment: why don't you just return the data that useGetStuff produces within the useCustomHook?

Answer (score 0):

You have done a pretty basic mistake where you are actually returning a new object on every hook call, so React does not know when to stop. While `useGetStuff` returns the whole object, so it should not be a problem, the second hook returns a new `{ someProperty };` object with new reference on every `component` call.

The way to fix that is to actually memoize the object:

```
const useCustomHook = () => {
    // some unrelated stuff
    const { data: stuffData, loading } = useGetStuff();
   
    // do logic with stuffData and other unrelated stuff

    return useMemo(() => {
        return { someProperty };
    }, [theThingThatShouldTriggerNewObjectCreation]);
}
```

You might also want to read a little bit more about such issues in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61717644/inifinite-loop-when-saving-an-object-from-async-await/61718404#comment109170342_61718404) question from StackOverflow.